# Bitmap image processing with masm32

Tags: image-processing, assembly, x86, masm32

I am working with masm 32. I want to process bitmap images. But I don't know how to get an image or save an image.
I have no idea about processing images with masm.
Any information will help me.
Thanks

Comment: Google, Wikipedia, BMP images. And the biggest one: actual effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you started... This is basic code to load in a bitmap and display it on a dialog box. I'm not sure what mean by 'processing' bitmap images, I suspect you need something more complex. However, this might get you started...

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

includelib user32.lib
includelib kernel32.lib
includelib shell32.lib
includelib comctl32.lib
includelib comdlg32.lib
includelib gdi32.lib

WinMain             PROTO :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD
WndProc             PROTO :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD

IDD_DIALOG          equ 1000

IDC_BITMAP          equ 100

IDM_MENU            equ 10000

.const

ClassName           db 'DLGCLASS',0


.data?

hInstance           dd ?
CommandLine         dd ?
hWnd                dd ?
hBitmap             dd ?



.code

start:

    invoke GetModuleHandle,NULL
    mov    hInstance,eax
    invoke GetCommandLine
    invoke InitCommonControls
    mov     CommandLine,eax
    invoke WinMain,hInstance,NULL,CommandLine,SW_SHOWDEFAULT
    invoke ExitProcess,eax

WinMain proc hInst:HINSTANCE,hPrevInst:HINSTANCE,CmdLine:LPSTR,CmdShow:DWORD
    LOCAL   wc:WNDCLASSEX
    LOCAL   msg:MSG

    mov     wc.cbSize,sizeof WNDCLASSEX
    mov     wc.style,CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW
    mov     wc.lpfnWndProc,offset WndProc
    mov     wc.cbClsExtra,NULL
    mov     wc.cbWndExtra,DLGWINDOWEXTRA
    push    hInst
    pop     wc.hInstance
    mov     wc.hbrBackground,COLOR_BTNFACE+1
    mov     wc.lpszMenuName, NULL
    mov     wc.lpszClassName,offset ClassName
    invoke LoadIcon,NULL,IDI_APPLICATION
    mov     wc.hIcon,eax
    mov     wc.hIconSm,eax
    invoke LoadCursor,NULL,IDC_ARROW
    mov     wc.hCursor,eax
    invoke RegisterClassEx,addr wc
    invoke CreateDialogParam,hInstance,IDD_DIALOG,NULL,addr WndProc,NULL
    invoke ShowWindow,hWnd,SW_SHOWNORMAL
    invoke UpdateWindow,hWnd
    .while TRUE
        invoke GetMessage,addr msg,NULL,0,0
      .BREAK .if !eax
        invoke TranslateMessage,addr msg
        invoke DispatchMessage,addr msg
    .endw
    mov     eax,msg.wParam
    ret

WinMain endp

WndProc proc hWin:HWND,uMsg:UINT,wParam:WPARAM,lParam:LPARAM
    LOCAL   ps:PAINTSTRUCT
    LOCAL   hdc:HDC
    LOCAL   hMemDC:HDC
    LOCAL   rect:RECT

    mov     eax,uMsg
    .if eax==WM_INITDIALOG
        push    hWin
        pop     hWnd

        ; Load up the bitmap
        invoke  LoadBitmap, hInstance, IDC_BITMAP
        mov     hBitmap, eax

    .elseif eax==WM_COMMAND
        mov     eax,wParam
        mov     edx, eax
        shr     edx, 16
        .if lParam==0 
            .if eax==IDM_FILE_EXIT
                invoke SendMessage,hWin,WM_CLOSE,0,0
            .elseif eax==IDM_HELP_ABOUT
                invoke ShellAbout,hWin,addr AppName,addr AboutMsg,NULL
            .endif
        .else

        .endif

    .elseif eax==WM_PAINT
        invoke  BeginPaint, hWnd, addr ps
        mov     hdc, eax
        invoke  CreateCompatibleDC, hdc
        mov     hMemDC, eax
        invoke  SelectObject, hMemDC, hBitmap
        invoke  GetClientRect, hWnd, addr rect
        invoke  BitBlt, hdc, 10, 10, rect.right, rect.bottom, hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCAND
        invoke  DeleteDC, hMemDC
        invoke  EndPaint, hWnd, addr ps
    .elseif eax==WM_CLOSE
        invoke DestroyWindow,hWin
    .elseif uMsg==WM_DESTROY
        invoke  DeleteObject, hBitmap
        invoke PostQuitMessage,NULL
    .else
        invoke DefWindowProc,hWin,uMsg,wParam,lParam
        ret
    .endif
    xor    eax,eax
    ret

WndProc endp

end start
```

Note the LoadBitmap API call and the WM_PAINT routine.

..Forgot the .rc file...

```
#define IDD_DIALOG 1000

#define IDC_BITMAP 100


IDC_BITMAP BITMAP DISCARDABLE "myfile.bmp"
```

Comment: I want to run some image processing algorithms on the image. I need to get value of pixels and change them in some cases. For example I want to make an binary image. If you have any more information It will help me. Thank you.